# Checking a string to see if it contains numeric character in UNIX

Tags: regex, string, bash, unix, if-statement

I'm new to UNIX, having only started it at work today, but experienced with Java, and have the following code:

```
#/bin/bash
echo "Please enter a word:"
read word
grep -i $word $1 | cut -d',' -f1,2 | tr "," "-"> output
```

This works fine, but what I now need to do is to check when word is read, that it contains nothing but letters and if it has numeric characters in print "Invalid input!" message and ask them to enter it again. I assumed regular expressions with an if statement would be the easy way to do this but I cannot get my head around how to use them in UNIX as I am used to the Java application of them. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, as I couldn't find help when searching as all the solutions with regular expressions in linux I found only dealt with if it was either all numeric or not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yet another approach. Grep exits with `0` if a match is found, so you can test the exit code:

```
echo "${word}" | grep -q '[0-9]'
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    echo 'Invalid input'
fi
```

This is `/bin/sh` compatible.

---

Incorporating Daenyth and John's suggestions, this becomes

```
if echo "${word}" | grep '[0-9]' >/dev/null; then
    echo 'Invalid input'
fi
```

Comment: `-q` to grep is not portable outside of GNU. If you want full portability (The only reason to ever use sh), use `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @Daenyth you're absolutely right, and I even did that when I tried it out on my system, then added the `-q` when I posted my answer. Seems I've been GNU-only for too long.

Comment: You can tighten this up by changing `cmd; if [ $? = 0]; then` to `if cmd; then`.

Comment: @John, think you missed "I'm new to UNIX", explicitness before cleverness.

Comment: @Anders it's not about cleverness, it's the same as the difference between doing `foo=returnTrue(); if (foo == true)` and `if (returnTrue())`

Comment: @Daenyth, Yeah I know, should have used another expression. Readability perhaps would be better. For someone new I feel it would be better to use explicitness and also to display $?

Comment: @Anders: In that case you should comment what `$?` means, because for someone new to bash, it's completely meaningless :P

Comment: @Stephen: The downside with using `echo` is that some shells treat `\\` as special, and some shells have special behavior if the first argument to `echo` begins with a `-`. A portable way of avoiding these pitfalls is to use `printf "%s\\n" "$word"` (or `printf %s "$word"` if you don't want a newline at the end).

Comment: @Gilles: I recalled that after 'tom' posted his "(quite) portable" answer and was looking into the actual portability of printf. It didn't exist as `man 1 printf` when I started shell programming, only as `man 3 printf` (the C function), and I tend to forget about it. Q: Would `printf "${word}"` work as well, or is the format specifier needed to prevent the interpretation of the '\' as an escape?

Comment: `printf` is a bash builtin, so it's not portable.

Comment: @Stephen: `printf` is not portable to unix systems from before the mid-1990s or so, but it's in POSIX. And `printf "$word"` would not work, any more than `printf(mystring);` would work in C: the first argument is a format, so `%` is special in it; in the shell an initial `-`, and a `\\` anywhere, are also special.

Comment: @Gilles: C `printf("some plain string");` with no format specifiers works just fine, as does `printf(varThatContainsFormat, var1, var2);`, and I tried the shell `printf "$somevar"` and that's fine too; the problem shows up in the difference between `printf "hello\n"` and `printf "%s" "hello\n"` -- the 1st prints *hello* followed by a newline, the 2nd prints *hello\n* showing the backslash and not printing a newline. Your advice is definitely sound, thanks.

Comment: @Stephen: The point is when your string comes in a variable and you can't know that it doesn't contain escape characters, `printf "$word" (or its C equivalent) doesn't do what you want unless you did intend "$word" to be a printf format (with 0 arguments) rather than a string`. It's a common mistake from C beginners.

Answer (score 10):

The double bracket operator is an extended version of the `test` command which supports regexes via the `=~` operator:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p "Please enter a word: " word
    if [[ $word =~ [0-9] ]]; then
        echo 'Invalid input!' >&2
    else
        break
    fi
done
```

This is a bash-specific feature. Bash is a newer shell that is not available on all flavors of UNIX--though by "newer" I mean "only recently developed in the post-vacuum tube era" and by "not all flavors of UNIX" I mean relics like old versions of Solaris and HP-UX.

In my opinion this is the simplest option and bash is plenty portable these days, but if being portable to old UNIXes is in fact important then you'll need to use the other posters' sh-compatible answers. sh is the most common and most widely supported shell, but the price you pay for portability is losing things like `=~`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to write portable shell code, your options for string manipulation are limited. You can use shell globbing patterns (which are a lot less expressive than regexps) in the `case` construct:

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
read word
while
  case "$word" in
    *[!A-Za-z]*) echo >&2 "Invalid input, please enter letters only"; true;;
    *) false;;
  esac
do
  read word
done
```

**EDIT**: setting `LC_COLLATE` is necessary because in most non-`C` locales, character ranges like `A-Z` don't have the “obvious” meaning. I assume you want only ASCII letters; if you also want letters with diacritics, don't change `LC_COLLATE`, and replace `A-Za-z` by `[:alpha:]` (so the whole pattern becomes `*[![:alpha:]]*`).

For full regexps, see the `expr` command. **EDIT**: Note that `expr`, like several other basic shell tools, has pitfalls with some special strings; the `z` characters below prevent `$word` from being interpreted as reserved words by `expr`.

```
export LC_COLLATE=C
read word
while expr "z$word" : 'z[A-Za-z]*$' >/dev/null; then
  echo >&2 "Invalid input, please enter letters only"
  read word
fi
```

If you only target recent enough versions of bash, there are other options, such as the `=~` operator of `[[ ... ]]` conditional commands.

Note that your last line has a bug, the first command should be

```
grep -i "$word" "$1"
```

The quotes are because somewhat counter-intuitively, `"$foo"` means “the value of the variable called `foo`” whereas plain `$foo` means “take the value of `foo`, split it into separate words where it contains whitespace, and treat each word as a globbing pattern and try to expand it”. (In fact if you've already checked that `$word` contains only letters, leaving the quotes won't do any harm, but it takes more time to think of these special cases than to just put the quotes every times.)

Comment: The case you have listed fails for non-ascii non-numeric input.

Comment: @Daenyth: true, all the solutions that use `A-Za-z` assume an ASCII locale. So let me add a footnote: if you want to allow all the letters in your locale (including letters with diacritics), replace `A-Za-z` by `[:alpha:]` everywhere (`case`, `expr`, `grep`, ...) (yes, you'll have brackets within brackets). If you only want ASCII letters, put `export LC_COLLATE=C` near the beginning of your script.

Comment: Simpler solution is just to invert it -- test that it contains `[^0-9]`. A whitelist is easier than a blacklist.

Comment: @Daenyth: It's not a whitelist/blacklist matter: `[^0-9]` would accept non-alphanumerics, whereas I think locky28 means to reject them. A better objection would have been that I used `expr` without protecting its arguments (fixed in my latest edit).

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I'm saying that you should test that it *doesn't* match. If any string foo matches `[^0-9]`, it contains invalid characters.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another (quite) portable way to do it ...

```
if test "$word" != "`printf "%s" "$word" | tr -dc '[[:alpha:]]'`"; then
   echo invalid
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

One portable (assuming bash >= 3) way to do this is to remove all numbers and test for length:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a number" var
if [[ -n ${var//[0-9]} ]]; then
    echo "Contains non-numbers!"
else
    echo "ok!"
fi
```

Coming from Java, it's important to note that bash has no real concept of objects or data types. Everything is a string, and complex data structures are painful at best.

For more info on what I did, and other related functions, google for bash string manipulation.

Comment: Assuming bash kitty? That's cruel.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with Bash parameter expansion and character classes:

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

word="abc1def"
word="abc,def"
word=$'abc\177def'
# cf. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/058 (no NUL byte in Bash variable)
word=$'abc\000def'   
word="abcdef"

(
set -xv
[[ "${word}" != "${word/[[:digit:]]/}" ]] && echo invalid || echo valid
[[ -n "${word//[[:alpha:]]/}" ]] && echo invalid || echo valid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's answers seem to be based on the fact that the only invalid characters are numbers. The initial questions states that they need to check that the string contains "nothing but letters".

I think the best way to do it is

```
nonalpha=$(echo "$word" | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]//g')
if [[ ${#nonalpha} -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Invalid character(s): $nonalpha"
fi
```

If you found this page looking for a way to detect non-numeric characters in your string (like I did!) replace [[:alpha:]] with [[:digit:]].